# Django's manage.py ANSI color code output in PyCharm

Tags: django, pycharm

I'm running django server over SSH connection on a remote interpreter in PyCharm 2.5.2.
In PyCharm console settings there are ANSI color definitions, so it seems that PyCharm *should* support them, but in my console window I do not see colors, just broken ANSI escape sequences like:

[image]

Comment: You should report this to the [PyCharm bugtracker](http://http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/PY)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not supported right now and this [feature request already exists in YouTrack](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-1925).